# can we declare variable dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Question 1:
with in  store procedure,can we declare variable dynamically like below:

```
declare @i int =1;
declare @s nvarchar(max) ='';
while(@i<5)  
begin 
set @s = concat('declare @temp',@i,' nvarchar(max);');
exec (@s);
set @i=@i + 1;
end
```

if we can declare the variable dynamically like above then what will be the scope of this kind of variable? with in that store procedure?

Question 2:
we do not need to declare session variable in mysql so can we have same kind of session variable in sql server.

Actually I am converting mysql script to sql server script and I am finding difficulties with variable declaration because in mysql I have used session variables.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no

You can declare the variable dynamically, and `exec` the command, but its scope will be within that `exec` statement, so it will vanish afterwards.

You can do

```
declare @t nvarchar(100) = 'declare @v int; select @v = 1; select @v+1'
exec (@t)
```

Or you can pass variables to commands with `sp_executesql`.